# How to display a 4x4 grid using bootstrap 3 on an iPhone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I want to use divs, but they're not working.
[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/P7fy5/2/). If you shrink the result screen, you will see that my divs go vertical.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Bootstrap 3</a>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by using below code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">3</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">3</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">3</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">3</div>
</div>
```

Here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7fy5/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace `sm` with `xs`... This will give you the "tiny" non-stacking grid:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/97005